# Error importing solution: The element 'entity' has invalid child element 'IsRetrieveAuditEnabled'

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

Importing a solution in a CRM environment it throws this error:

> The element 'entity' has invalid child element
>   'IsRetrieveAuditEnabled'

Details:

```
The element 'entity' has invalid child element 'IsRetrieveAuditEnabled'. 
List of possible elements expected: 'IsMappable, IsVisibleInMobile, 
CanModifyDuplicateDetectionSettings, CanModifyMailMergeSettings, 
CanModifyConnectionSettings, CanCreateAttributes, IsReplicationUserFiltered, 
IntroducedVersion, CanModifyMobileVisibility, IsCustomizable, 
CanModifyMobileClientReadOnly, CanModifyMobileClientVisibility, 
CanModifyQueueSettings, MobileOfflineFilters, EnforceStateTransitions, 
EntityMask, EntityKeys, IconMediumName, CanChangeHierarchicalRelationship, 
DaysSinceRecordLastModified, IsActivityParty, CanBeRelatedEntityInRelationship, 
CanBePrimaryEntityInRelationship, IsReplicated, AutoCreateAccessTeams, IconSmallName, 
IsReadOnlyInMobileClient, ActivityTypeMask, CanModifyMobileClientOffline, 
CanEnableSyncToExternalSearchIndex, IsMailMergeEnabled, EntityHelpUrl, IsRenameable, 
HasRelatedActivities, ChangeTrackingEnabled, CanModifyAuditSettings, 
IsEnabledForExternalChannels, IsMapiGridEnabled, IsReadingPaneEnabled, 
IsOfflineInMobileClient, HasRelatedFeedback, CanBeInManyToMany, CanChangeTrackingBeEnabled, 
IsVisibleInMobileC....names><Descriptions>
<Description description="Código de la zona horaria que estaba en uso cuando se creó el registro." languagecode="3082" />
</Descriptions></attribute></attributes><EntitySetName>xxx_entitynames</EntitySetName>
<IsDuplicateCheckSupported>0</IsDuplicateCheckSupported><IsBusinessProcessEnabled>0</IsBusinessProcessEnabled>
<IsRequiredOffline>0</IsRequiredOffline><IsInteractionCentricEnabled>0</IsInteractionCentricEnabled>
<IsCollaboration>0</IsCollaboration><AutoRouteToOwnerQueue>0</AutoRouteToOwnerQueue><IsConnectionsEnabled>0</IsConnectionsEnabled>
<EntityColor></EntityColor><IsDocumentManagementEnabled>0</IsDocumentManagementEnabled>
<IsOneNoteIntegrationEnabled>0</IsOneNoteIntegrationEnabled><IsKnowledgeManagementEnabled>0</IsKnowledgeManagementEnabled>
<IsSLAEnabled>0</IsSLAEnabled><IsDocumentRecommendationsEnabled>0</IsDocumentRecommendationsEnabled><IsBPFEntity>0</IsBPFEntity>
<OwnershipTypeMask>UserOwned</OwnershipTypeMask><IsAuditEnabled>0</IsAuditEnabled><IsRetrieveAuditEnabled>0</IsRetrieveAuditEnabled>
<IsRetrieveMultipleAuditEnabled>0</IsRetrieveMultipleAuditEnabled><IsActivity>0</IsActivity><ActivityTypeMask></ActivityTypeMask>
<IsActivityParty>0</IsActivityParty><IsReplicated>0</IsReplicated><IsReplicationUserFiltered>0</IsReplicationUserFiltered>
<IsMailMergeEnabled>1</IsMailMergeEnabled><IsVisibleInMobile>0</IsVisibleInMobile><IsVisibleInMobileClient>0</IsVisibleInMobileClient>
<IsReadOnlyInMobileClient>0</IsReadOnlyInMobileClient><IsOfflineInMobileClient>0</IsOfflineInMobileClient>
<DaysSinceRecordLastModified>0</DaysSinceRecordLastModified><MobileOfflineFilters></MobileOfflineFilters>
<IsMapiGridEnabled>1</IsMapiGridEnabled><IsReadingPaneEnabled>0</IsReadingPaneEnabled><IsQuickCreateEnabled>0</IsQuickCreateEnabled>
<SyncToExternalSearchIndex>0</SyncToExternalSearchIndex><IntroducedVersion>1.6.0.1</IntroducedVersion><IsCustomizable>1</IsCustomizable>
<IsRenameable>1</IsRenameable><IsMappable>1</IsMappable><CanModifyAuditSettings>1</CanM
```

If I remove these two elements from customizations.xml:

```
<IsRetrieveAuditEnabled>0</IsRetrieveAuditEnabled>
<IsRetrieveMultipleAuditEnabled>0</IsRetrieveMultipleAuditEnabled>
```

The solution pass the validation before importing. This is an onpremise CRM.

I am not sure what this error could be and there is literally nothing about **IsRetrieveAuditEnabled** on internet.

How can I fix this when I am exporting the solution?

Comment: Perhaps your target CRM environment is older than your source environment? I just exported an entity and those fields were included in my customisations.xml

Comment: I also found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4078187/service-update-8-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-8-2-2

Comment: Thank you, when I was searching before, there wasn't anything about IsRetrieveAuditEnabled, I am going to look at my CRM version and I will update the post with details

Comment: @jasonscript That was the problem, one environment version was 8.2.2 and the other one was 8.2.1, please post it like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4078187/service-update-8-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-8-2-2) on the Microsoft Support site that suggests these fields were removed in Service Update 8 for Microsoft Dynamics 365 8.2.2.

> **Service Update 8 resolves the following issues:**
>
> - Remove export handlers for IsRetrieveAuditEnabled and IsRetrieveMultipleAuditEnabled

This problem may be a result of mismatching CRM environment versions. Please make sure that your source environment is the same version as the target environment